# Looping through an array of objects and mapping each object them to a single template object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a two sets of data, one formatted like so:

```
    title: "Test Json",
    showProgressBar: "top",
    showQuestionNumbers: "off",
    pages: [
        {
            questions: [
                {
                    type: "",
                    name: "",
                    title: "",
                    hasOther: true,
                    isRequired: true,
                    colCount: 4,
                    choices: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

The other formatted like so:

```
{Answers: "“18-24”, “25-50”, “50+”",
​
Question: "How old are you?",
​
QuestionNumber: "1",
​
isRequired: "TRUE",
​
type: "radiogroup"}
```

This second set of data is multiple of these objects, which I am looping through using a `forEach` loop like so:

```
data.forEach((data, i)=>{
     console.log(data)
// returns above object x3 
})
```

What I want to do is use the first object and map values to the `questions` array using the values of the second object, so for example `questions[0].type` would be mapped to `data.type`.

I have managed to figure out mapping one object to the template doing this:

```
data.forEach((data, i)=>{
     console.log(data)
     questions[0].type = data.type
     questions[0].name = data.Question
     questions[0].title = data.Question
     questions[0].choices = [data.Answers]
})
```

But this only maps the first object in the data array of objects, and I want to basically create a new template object based on the number of objects in the data array and create as many 'filled questions templates' as there is objects in data array

Any pointers and help would be lovely <3

Comment: u can use `map()` for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Where would I put the map to ensure it maps all the objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
data.forEach((data, i)=>{
     console.log(data)
     questions.push([{
      type: data.type
      name: data.Question
      title: data.Question
      choices: [data.Answers]
    }])
})
```

Updated this answer with your additional question

Comment: `questions[i].name` and `questions[i].title` are the same

Comment: I copied that from your update, all i added was the letter `i` where you had `0`. The reason it only creates one object is because adding `[0]` is only targetting the first item in the questions array

Comment: i am not the OP :D

Comment: They are supposed to be the same, the first object has a name and title property

Comment: But this still only returns one object

Comment: @messerbill haha sorry about that

Comment: @ljm222 oh right sorry, this should create and object for each item in the data: 
`data.forEach((data, i)=>{
     console.log(data)
     questions.push({
       type = data.type
        name = data.Question
        title = data.Question
        choices = [data.Answers]
    })
})`

Comment: Brilliant this worked with some slight changes:                 ```data.forEach((data, i)=>{
                    console.log(data)
                    objectNeeded.push({ type : data.type, name : data.Question, title : data.Question, choices : [data.Answers] })
                    console.log(objectNeeded) 
                })```

Comment: ahh yeah, my mind was still in c# mode with the '=' lol, glad i could help

Comment: Do you know how I would wrap an array around the object I am pushing?

Comment: Just edited my original answer above with the answer

Comment: If I wanted on each loop to create a new ```questions``` object on each map, and add it to the ```pages``` array is this much different?

Comment: Pretty much similar logic to the one above except you're pushing into the `pages` array - have a go an pm me if you have any trouble

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211982/discussion-between-ljm222-and-chma).